# Does $(T_j^{i} + T_i^j)$ is a tensor in general?

Tags: tensors

I am studying tensors for the first time and I have the following doubt:

If $(T_j^i)$ is a mixed tensor,  $(T_j^{i} + T_i^j)$ is neccesary a tensor o not? It is not so clear to me. Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That the indices are at different heights in the two terms tells us this isn't a tensor, because you're mixing different transformation rules. But let's explore your index-exchanging goal here. If $T^{ik}$ isn't symmetric, $T^i_j$ is unclear notation, which is why we distinguish $T^i_{\:j}$ from $T^{\:i}_j$; these two terms *can* be added to form a tensor viz.$$T^i_{\:j}+T^{\:i}_j=T^{ik}g_{kj}+g_{jk}T^{ki}=(T^{ik}+T^{ki})g_{jk}.$$